# как открыть Меню привязанное к ttk.Menubutton при наведении на него?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

Хотел сделать кастомную строку меню в `Tkinter`, но т.к. ее настроить было нельзя, пришлось делать костыли. Я сделал кастомное меню из `Frame`, `Button` и `Menubutton`. Но встретился с небольшой проблемой - не могу открыть Меню при наведении на `ttk.Menubutton`. То есть мне надо чтобы при наведении на `Menubutton` открывалось Меню, привязанное к данной кнопке(имитировалось нажатие на `Menubutton`). Как такое можно реализовать?

### Минимально рабочий код

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

root.option_add("*Menu.borderWidth", "0")
root.option_add("*Menu.activeBorderWidth", "0")
root.option_add("*Menu.background", "black")


style = ttk.Style(root)

fr = ttk.Frame(root)

btn_menu = ttk.Menubutton(fr, text='fegvd')
btn_menu.grid(row=0, column=0)

btn =ttk.Button(fr, text='grfbvgfev')
btn.grid(row=0, column=1)

btn_menu_st = ttk.Menubutton(fr, text='Gds')
btn_menu_st.grid(row=0, column=2)

fr.pack(fill='x')


file = tk.Menu(btn_menu, tearoff=0, foreground='white')
file.add_command(label='ГЫГ')

style = tk.Menu(btn_menu_st, tearoff=0, foreground='white')
style.add_command(label='Ugu')

btn_menu.configure(menu=file)
btn_menu_st.configure(menu=style)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49888623/tkinter-hovering-over-button-color-change

Comment: @splash58, это конечно хорошо, вот только об этом я знал. Мне нужен способ имитации нажатия на эту кнопку. То есть чтобы при наведении на эти `Menubutton'ы` они раскрывались и появлялись меню, привязанные к ним

Comment: Способ появления Меню как при клике правой мыши не подходит, т.к. выглядит некрасиво(при нажатии на `Menubutton` меню появляется только в том месте, где это указано при создании `Menubutton`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы сымитировать нажатие можно вызвать `event_generate('<<Invoke>>'))` на нужном вижджете

```
btn_menu.bind("<Enter>", lambda e: e.widget.event_generate('<<Invoke>>'))
```